# Upload Product Images By CSV

Tags: magento2.3, csv, image-upload

I want to upload small, thumbnail and swatch image to many products by CSV. Images will be the same.

When I import csv, the process is showing success and I can see those images are uploaded at the backend but not showing on frontend.

I already copy images on : /pub/media/import/

Please check the image of my csv.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this command:

```
php bin/magento catalog:images:resize
```